# How often is the Stack Overflow's public data dump updated?

Tags: support, data-dump

I'd like to automate the creation of activity reports on Stack Overflow. I'm hoping to use the public data dump that Stack Overflow has made available. Can you please tell me how often it's updated?

Answer (score 10):

The data dump hosted on archive.org isn't even close to daily - it's updated every 3 months, give or take.

The [Data Explorer instance](http://data.stackexchange.com) is updated every week on Sunday.

The [public API](http://api.stackexchange.com) is effectively instant.