# How can I get a notification when a new Stack Exchange dump is made available?

Tags: support, notifications, data-dump

How can I get a notification when a new [Stack Exchange dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19579/178179) is made available?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, neither Stack Exchange nor the *Internet Archive* provide any satisfactory way to track or alert about Dump uploads, see below.

- You can see [a user-maintained approximation of dump dates here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/all-stack-exchange-data-dumps).
- Or login to the Internet Archive and only then can you see the history of dump uploads at [catalogd.archive.org/history/stackexchange](https://catalogd.archive.org/history/stackexchange) (Note the `submittime` column.)

The Data Dump [nominally updates quarterly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286103/how-often-is-the-stack-overflows-public-data-dump-updated) but my *recollection* over the years is that [the interval and the release dates are rather sporadic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239147/update-frequency-of-se-data-dump-on-web-archive).

For alerts about availability, the only current option seems to be to use **a third-party monitoring service** like [Follow That Page](https://www.followthatpage.com/) or similar.

---

Things I tried and that failed:

- [Search Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Data%20Dump%22%20update).
- [Search the SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/cc-wiki-dump/).
- [Search the Internet Archive for "track"/"watch"/"alert"/"monitor" capability](https://help.archive.org/hc/en-us). Found none.
- Favorited the *Stack Exchange Data Dump* entry -- this added no useful alert activity, even on my favorites RSS feed.
- Used [Internet Archive's "Advanced Search"](https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php) to create [an RSS feed](https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php?q=identifier%3Astackexchange&fl%5B%5D=identifier&fl%5B%5D=oai_updatedate&fl%5B%5D=title&sort%5B%5D=&sort%5B%5D=&sort%5B%5D=&rows=50&page=1&callback=callback&save=yes&output=rss#raw).  But due to design limitations such feeds are useless for update tracking.
- You *can* create [a JSON URL that returns the last update date](https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php?q=identifier%3Astackexchange&fl%5B%5D=identifier&fl%5B%5D=oai_updatedate&fl%5B%5D=title&sort%5B%5D=createdate+desc&sort%5B%5D=&sort%5B%5D=&rows=50&page=1&output=json&callback=callback#raw), though.
  So if you have some mechanism to poll that URL once everyday or so, that should show if something new is available.
- Note that even archive.org's own wayback machine [does not track changes to the data dump upload very well](https://web.archive.org/web/20171015000000*/https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).